# Hbase Client Scanner Hangs

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have been using Hbase for months and I have loaded Hbase table with more than 6GB of data. When I tried scanning the rows using Java client it hangs and reports the following error,

```
Could not seek StoreFileScanner[HFileScanner for reader reader=hdfs
```

Further if I login to shell and scan it works perfectly and even Java client scanner works fine for hbase table having small amount of data.

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

For large data you can write map reduce code. simple Java programs are not really very effective when it comes to big data. You can look into pig script to achieve that.

Check out these for further help :

http://sujee.net/tech/articles/hadoop/hbase-map-reduce-freq-counter/

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/MapReduce

http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/package-summary.html

Or else you can give a try to Pig Scripts also for mapt reduce programs.

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseTableInputFormat.html

One more option is there you increase the HBase time out Property and give a try. From different HBase configuration setting you can refer:

http://hbase.apache.org/docs/r0.20.6/hbase-conf.html

But when it comes to large data Map-reduce code is always better, and you can also search for optimizing guidelines/best practices for hbase.